# NDsolve on ODE returns "non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`."

Tags: differential-equations, debugging

The input is:

```
>NDSolve[{a'[t] == -I (-0.823 + 0.000005*2*Abs ((b[t]))) a[t] - a[t]*0.04 /2, 
  b'[t] == -I (b[t]*(-0.823) + 0.000005*Re (a[t]))^2 - a[t]*0.09/2, 
  a[0] == b[0] == 0.1}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 200}]

`NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.
```

Even I change {t,0,200} to {t,10,200} it says the same, which really confuses me.

I can solve it successfully with matlab using "OED45" fuc but almost identical expressions fails on mathematica. I am new to this language and I guess it's the grammar problem because of the appearance of complex numbers maybe?

Comment: Write Abs and Re with square brackets `Abs [b[t]] ` and `Re[a[t]] ` and everything is ok.

Comment: In Mathematica all fun functions, including such as ` Abs` and `Re` require the arguments within the square brackets. That is, not `Abs ((b[t]))` and `Re (a[t])`, but `Abs[b[t]]` and `Re[a[t]]`. After I fixed this, your code returned a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**modified**

If you choose the right brackets (Mathematica uses squared brackets `[]` for functions ) you'll get a result

```
sol= NDSolve[{a'[t] == -I (-0.823 + 0.000005*2*Abs [ b[t]]) a[t] -a[t]*0.04/2,b'[t] == -I (b[t]*(-0.823) + 0.000005*Re[a[t]])^2 - a[t]*0.09/2,a[0] == b[0] == 0.1}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

To access the solution and/or the derivatives simply substitude `sol`

```
{ a[t],b[t],a'[t],b'[t]} /.sol
```

Comment: Such a stupid question.....Thank u so much! And can I ask more about mathematica? Could you give some suggestions if I want to plot a figure for b'[t] and b[t]?

Comment: @BenXylona There are no stupid questions...See my modified asnwer.